# getline line by line and then store entire lines in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, getline, line-by-line

I'm trying to store every line separately in an array of strings. It doesn't work the way I've written it obviously all I'm getting when I try to print array[0] is the last line of the textfile. But when I print the variable "line" inside of the while loop I can print every single line in the text file but I can only seem to store the last line of the txt file.

Is this possible to do? Or is this a limitation of getline..?

```
int main()
{
  FILE * fp;
  char *line;
  ssize_t read;
  size_t bufsize = 32;
  int i=0;

  char **array;

  array = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
  line = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char)); 
  fp = fopen("testing.txt", "r"); 

  while ((getline(&line, &bufsize, fp)) != -1) { 
    printf("%s", line);
    array[i] = line;
    i++;
  } 
  fclose(fp);  
  printf("%s", array[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "every line **separately** in an array of strings". And what makes you think a **single** `malloc` for a **single** line will make that **seperate** storage for **each** line?

Comment: `array` is an array of *pointers* to `char`. So you want `array = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));` (not `sizeof(char)`). Your `malloc` doesn't allocate enough memory for `bufsize` pointers.

Comment: `getline` is not standard. Use `fgets`. And `EOF` is not necessarily `-1`. Do not use magic numbers in your code!

Comment: One of the convenient things about `getline()` is that it can allocate the strings for you...

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'm a beginner, my teacher advised us to use getline because "it can handle most larger lines better". I will try both!

Comment: @felle: He might be a typical teacher which only know his toolchain&libraries, but has no idea there is an international C standard (C11) and his toolchain is not the centre of the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already has been mentioned, you need to allocate space for pointers, not chars:

```
char **array;
array = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
```

Also you need to allocate space for separate lines, and copy lines to it:

```
while ((getline(&line, &bufsize, fp)) != -1) {
  printf("%s", line);
  array[i] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
  strcpy(array[i], line);
  i++;
}
```

A mistake in your code is that all `array[i]` points to the same string in variable `line`, which is refilled by `getline()` every loop cycle.

It may be useful to read manual about [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline). It permits allocation of strings by itself, but don't forget to use free().

```
array[0] = NULL;
while ((getline(&array[i], &bufsize, fp)) != -1) {
  printf("%s", array[i]);
  array[i + 1] = NULL;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helpful advice and taking your time. Manual gave some clarity aswell.

Answer (score 0):

This does not make an array of strings:

```
char **array;
array = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
```

There are plenty of resources that describe how to do this. eg. [How to create a dynamic array of strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5935956/1294207)
Essentially, you need to allocate space for the array, then allocate space for each the strings, a standard way might be:

```
char **arrayOfStrings;
unsigned int numberOfElements = 20, sizeOfEachString = 100;
arrayOfStrings = malloc(numberOfElements * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements ; i++)
    arrayOfStrings[i] = malloc(sizeOfEachString  * sizeof(char));
```

As a further note, for your `while`loop:

```
while (getline(&line, &bufsize, fp)) {
```

Is sufficient. Getline will return 0 once you have finished your file. [Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

```
char **array;



array = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));

array[i] = line;
```

I think your problem is with array, you are indeed dynamically allocating memory for array but not array[i].

```
while ((getline(&line, &bufsize, fp)) != -1) { 
array[i]=malloc(sizeof(char) * (bufsize+1));
printf("%s", line);
array[i] = line;
i++;
```

}

This should fix it

Edit after testing the program:

```
array = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
```

should be

```
array = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
```