# Copy a string to a malloc'd array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, malloc, strncpy

I thought I understood the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935933/dynamically-create-an-array-of-strings-with-malloc) but I don't.  I understand the first result but I still don't know how to do the copy correctly.  I tried the following code:

```
// TstStrArr.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>


int main()
{
    char ** StrPtrArr;
    char    InpBuf0[] = "TstFld0";
    char    InpBuf1[] = "TstFld1";

    StrPtrArr = (char **)malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));

    StrPtrArr[0] = (char *)malloc(10 + 1);
    printf("inpbuf=%s   sizeof=%2d   ", InpBuf0, sizeof(StrPtrArr[0]));
    strncpy_s(StrPtrArr[0], sizeof(StrPtrArr[0]), InpBuf0, _TRUNCATE);
    printf("strptrarr=%s\n", StrPtrArr[0]);

    StrPtrArr[1] = (char *)malloc(10 + 1);
    printf("inpbuf=%s   sizeof=%2d   ", InpBuf1, sizeof(*StrPtrArr[1]));
    strncpy_s(*StrPtrArr[1], sizeof(*StrPtrArr[1]), InpBuf1, _TRUNCATE);    //  error here
    printf("*strptrarr=%s\n", StrPtrArr[1]);

    free(StrPtrArr[0]);
    free(StrPtrArr[1]);
    free(StrPtrArr);


    return 0;
}
```

The result I got was:

```
inpbuf=TstFld0   sizeof= 4   strptrarr=Tst
inpbuf=TstFld1   sizeof= 1
```

and the following error:

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.
destination_it was 0xFFFFFFCD.
```

The result I thought I'd get was either of the following:

```
inpbuf=TstFld1   sizeof=11   *strptrarr=TstFld1
inpbuf=TstFld1   sizeof= 1   *strptrarr=T
```

I understand the first copy copied the input buffer to the 4 byte pointer which was incorrect.  I thought the second copy would copy the input buffer to the value of the dereferenced pointer of a size of 11 but it didn't.  I'm guessing the copy was to the first character of the string in the array.  I don't understand memory enough to know the significance of the address 0xFFFFFFCD but I guess it's in read-only memory thus causing the error.

What is the correct way to do the copy?

(I don't think it matters, but I'm using VS 2015 Community Edition Update 3.)

Comment: sizeof will not give you string length.

Comment: Thank you.  That's true.  I believe the second parm of MS version of `strncpy` needs to be the `sizeof` the receiver variable.

Comment: What is `_TRUNCATE`? It does not look like you use `strncpy_s` correctly. See the [specification](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.7.1.4)

Comment: Thank you, Olaf.  I checked the specification and `_truncate` is used when the number of characters to copy is greater than the `sizeof` the receiver variable.  When I specified the `strlen(of the input buffer)` I got a "buffer too small" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why

```
  strncpy_s(*StrPtrArr[1], sizeof(*StrPtrArr[1]), InpBuf1, _TRUNCATE);
```

?

`*StrPtrArr[1]` should be `StrPtrArr[1]` because `StrPtrArr` is of type `char**` and you need `char*` here.

and sizeof(*StrPtrArr[1]) - is quite strange....
actually `sizeof(StrPtrArr[1])` also cannot provide correct value.

You should remember size of allocated memory and then use it like:

```
 size_t arrSize = 10 + 1;
 StrPtrArr[1] = (char *)malloc(arrSize);
 . . .
 strncpy_s(StrPtrArr[1], arrSize, InpBuf1, _TRUNCATE);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried the change, but got the same error on the copy.  I was hoping the sizeof(*StrPtrArr) would be 11.

Comment: Try strlen instead of sizeof.

Comment: @koper89 Good suggestion, but it is better to use `strlen(StrPtrArr[1]) + 1` to copy `'\0'` also

Comment: I tried the following code with the hard-coded length of 11:  `strncpy_s(*StrPtrArr[1], 11, InpBuf1, _TRUNCATE);`.  I hate to say but I still get the error on that line, too.

Comment: Command should be `strncpy_s(StrPtrArr[1], arrSize, InpBuf1, _TRUNCATE); ` : `*StrPtrArr[1]` -> `StrPtrArr[1]` (no * needed)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Thank you so much @VolAnd!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `sizeof` when deciding how many characters to copy. However, you allocated a fixed number of characters which is not known to `sizeof` operator: `sizeof StrPtrArr[0]` is equal to the size of `char` pointer on your system (four bytes, judging from the output), not 10 + 1. Hence, you need to specify that same number again in the call to secure string copy.

Comment: Thank you.  Is this what you mean:  `strncpy_s(*StrPtrArr[1], 8, InpBuf1, _TRUNCATE);`?  I still got the same error as above.

Comment: @J.Toran 8 should be 11, and there is no asterisk in front of StrPtrArr[1].

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight.  I believe this is the same correction that VolAnd showed above.  Unfortunately I could only specifiy one correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't as complicated as people seem to think.

```
char* array = calloc( n, sizeof(array[0]) ); // allocate array of pointers

// assign a dynamically allocated pointer:
size_t size = strlen(str) + 1;
array[i] = malloc(size);
memcpy(array[i], str, size);
```

I intentionally used `calloc` during allocation, since that sets all pointers to NULL. This gives the advantage that you can harmlessly call `free()` on the pointer, even before it is assigned to point at a string.

This in turn means that you can easily (re)assign a new string to an index at any time, in the following way:

```
void str_assign (char** dst, const char* src)
{
  size_t size = strlen(src) + 1;
  free(*dst);
  *dst = malloc(size);
  if(*dst != NULL)
  {
    memcpy(*dst, src, size);
  }
}

...
str_assign(&array[i], "something");
```

Comment: Thank you @Lundin.  This is also a correct answer.  I'm still somewhat of a beginner and hadn't used `memcpy` before, but I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @J.Toran `memcpy` is a general copy function for any kind of memory. It does the same thing as `strcpy_s`, although `strcpy_s` also checks if the source string has reached the end. Since this code already knew how long the source string was by the call to `strlen`, I could use `memcpy` instead of `strcpy_s` - `memcpy` is ever so slightly faster.

Comment: if 'n' is known, say 1024, would this be equivalent to your calloc?
`char* array[1024] = {NULL};`