# How to detect end of 'array of strings'? (in c)

Tags: arrays, c, string, multidimensional-array, text-files

If you are confused with "Array of strings" it is basically `char arr[10][10];`. I'm trying to type out an array of strings using 'for' loop, and the length of that array of strings is unknown (it's variable). How do I write a 'for' loop that would know where is the end of that array of strings and stop writing? (btw if you're curious as to what I'm needing, it is for a system that reads strings from a text file line by line and puts them in an array of strings) I can however detect EOF, so right now I'm using a for loop that puts lines in an array of strings, and immediately prints it... here it is:

```
fp = fopen ("file.txt","r");
for(i=0;!feof(fp);i++)
{
    fgets(array[i],20,fp);
    printf("\n%s",array[i]);
}
fclose(fp)
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/41195151

Comment: Pleae provide a [mre] which demonstrates the undesired behaviour with specified sample input.

Comment: If `array` is an actual 2-D array, you can determine the number of rows by `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`. If `array` is actually a pointer to the first row of a 2-D array (e.g. from a function parameter) then it needs to be told how many rows there are (e.g. by another function parameter).

Answer (score 2):

Just check the return value of `fgets()` and keep a counter, when you get a `NULL` pointer, there is (probably) nothing more to read from the file.

```
   char array[10][10];
   FILE *fp = fopen ("file.txt","r");
   size_t max_size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
   size_t length = 0;


    while (length < max_size && fgets(array[length], sizeof(array[0]), fp) != NULL)
    {
        length++;
    }

   printf("%zu\n", length);
   fclose(fp);
```

But note that you might go out of bounds if it happens there are more than 10 lines in the file. You should also check that `length` is within the bounds of the array.

*[`fgets()` will also set `errno` to indicate the error, if you are on a POSIX-like system.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html)*

Also, see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) and [Why it's bad to use feof() to control a loop](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1046476070).

Comment: **"fgets() will also set errno to indicate the error"** -- That is a requirement of POSIX, but ISO C does not require this.

Comment: alex01011, Can't up-vote answer with "fgets() will also set errno to indicate the error." as that is not what the C standard specifies.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have rephrased , but is what you state correct according to [this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html)?

Comment: Yes I am correct per the C spec.  Your reference is not the C spec.  See [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/2410359) and [fgets()](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2).  IAC, `errno` is not needed to discern the result of `fgets()`.