# How do I fill a string array from a textfile using double pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, readfile, double-pointer

I'm trying to read a file and save the strings in an array using pointers, but I'm having problems. Can someone give me suggestions of what to do?

```
// not allowed to change these two rows
char **Lines;
Lines = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*maxLines);

...

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(fileName, "r");     // fileName already exists here
int i=0, j=0;

while(i<maxLines){
    Lines[i] = (char*)malloc(maxLength * sizeof(char)); 
    i++;
}

// No string will be longer than "maxLenght" so no buffer is used.
while(fgets(Lines[j] , maxLength, (FILE*) fp) != NULL && j < maxLines) 
{
        j++
}
```

I want to fill "Lines" with each string in the file. I keep getting segmentation fault.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935933/dynamically-create-an-array-of-strings-with-malloc

Comment: Also have a look at [a list of helpful C resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You allocated an array of pointers (one for each line) but didn't allocate memory for any of *them*. You can read each line into a generous buffer first so you know how long it is, then allocate enough memory and copy it.

Comment: This question, or a variant of it, gets asked multiple times a day. Please search before asking!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read the content of a file to a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174531/how-to-read-the-content-of-a-file-to-a-string-in-c)

Comment: @WeatherVane i made some changes but i'm still segment faulting. Thanks for the suggestion regarding the buffer but as a start i will only use sizes below "maxlength".

Comment: @dandan78 I'm not having problems reading data from a file, the problem is storing it in the manner i want. I did not find those examples useful, I'm sorry.

Comment: I don't know if it accounts for the segfault, but in the second loop `i < maxLines` should be `j < maxLines`.

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah that fixed it. But that was a silly mistake, your input that i need to allocate memory earlier was very important. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second while loop replace "||" with "&&".

The loop in this case continues to execute even when after maxlines has reached.

Comment: That was a silly mistake by me. thanks.
I'm still getting segment faults tho :(

Comment: Now that you are using j for fgets, use j<maxlines. i is already at maxlines.

Comment: This silly issue and another issue with that WeatherVane solved fixed it. thanks!