# Creation of Dynamic Array of Strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, dynamic-arrays

So I am pretty much trying to create an array that functions as following:
1)I enter a string (in a temporary array like char temp[...] for example)
2)I create a while loop that ends when the first character of temp is \x0
3)Inside the loop I use the malloc function to create space for each string
4)I print the strings

Problem is that whenever i try to run my program it crushes and the compiler isn't helping me much.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LINE 80

int main(){
    char **pin;
    char temp[LINE];
    int index = 0;
    puts("Gimme Books' Titles:");
    gets(temp);
    while(temp[0] != '\x0'){
        pin[index] = (char*)malloc(strlen(temp)+1);
        strcpy(pin[index], temp);
        index++;
        gets(temp);
    }
    puts("\nBooks' List:");
    for(int k = 0; k < index; k++){
        puts(pin[k]);
    }
}
```

Anyone here who can help me find out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `pin` is uninitialized. You need to allocate space for the pointers you allocate in the loop. If you don't have a fixed size then you will also need to keep track of how many slots you've allocated and realloc if you need more space.

Comment: Worth a read and a switch to `fgets`: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am actually so confused right now. You mean that I have to allocate space for the size of the array and the size of the strings as well? If i got that correctly would you be kind enough to help me?

Comment: [Dynamically create an array of strings with malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935933/dynamically-create-an-array-of-strings-with-malloc) has some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in the comments above [mostly] assumes that we know the number of elements *before* we allocate the array.

Thus, it's *not* as useful when we can only get the number of elements by reading the input file. For TTY input from `stdin` this won't work too well because we can't rewind the file.

A dynamic array is generally useful. So, I've created one that allows arbitrarily sized array elements. And, it can grow/expand as we add new elements.

And, for demo purposes here, I've created a "book" structure that stores Author's name and book title.

Here is the code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>

// general dynamic array control
typedef struct {
    void *arr_base;                         // pointer to data
    size_t arr_size;                        // bytes / element
    size_t arr_count;                       // number of elements in use
    size_t arr_capacity;                    // number of elements allocated
} arr_t;

// book control
typedef struct {
    char *book_last;                        // author's last name
    char *book_first;                       // author's first name
    char *book_title;                       // book title
} book_t;

// arrnew -- allocate new array
arr_t *
arrnew(size_t siz)
{
    arr_t *arr = calloc(1,sizeof(*arr));

    // store the number of bytes in each element
    arr->arr_size = siz;

    return arr;
}

// arrappend -- get new element in array
// RETURNS: pointer to element
void *
arrappend(arr_t *arr)
{
    size_t index;
    void *ptr;

    // get index of element to store into and increase the in use count
    index = arr->arr_count++;

    do {
        // we have enough space for the new element already
        if (arr->arr_count < arr->arr_capacity)
            break;

        // increase allocated amount
        // NOTE: the increment is arbitrary
        arr->arr_capacity += 10;

        // grow the array
        arr->arr_base = realloc(arr->arr_base,
            arr->arr_capacity * arr->arr_size);

        // got the larger array
        if (arr->arr_base != NULL)
            break;

        perror("arrappend");
        exit(1);
    } while (0);

    // point to element we can store into
    ptr = arr->arr_base;
    ptr += index * arr->arr_size;

    return ptr;
}

// arrtrim -- trim array to number of elements actually used
void
arrtrim(arr_t *arr)
{

    arr->arr_capacity = arr->arr_count;
    arr->arr_base = realloc(arr->arr_base,arr->arr_capacity * arr->arr_size);

    if (arr->arr_base == NULL) {
        perror("arrtrim");
        exit(1);
    }
}

// arrfree -- free up array storage
void
arrfree(arr_t *arr)
{

    free(arr->arr_base);
    free(arr);
}

int
main(void)
{
    char buf[300];
    char *cp;
    book_t *book;

    // echo line if input is _not_ a tty [mostly for demo]
    struct termios tio;
    int echo = tcgetattr(fileno(stdin),&tio) < 0;

    // get new array
    arr_t *arr = arrnew(sizeof(book_t));

    printf("Gimme Books's Titles:\n");

    while (1) {
        // get next line -- stop on EOF
        char *cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // echo line if input is _not_ a tty
        if (echo)
            fputs(buf,stdout);

        // strip newline
        buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = 0;

        // stop on blank line
        if (buf[0] == 0)
            break;

        // get new book struct
        book = arrappend(arr);

        // get author's last name
        char *tok = strtok(buf," \t");
        book->book_last = strdup(tok);

        // get author's first name
        tok = strtok(NULL," \t");
        book->book_first = strdup(tok);

        // get the book title
        tok += strlen(tok);
        ++tok;
        for (;  *tok != 0;  ++tok) {
            if (*tok != ' ')
                break;
        }
        book->book_title = strdup(tok);
    }

    arrtrim(arr);

    // show all the books
    book = arr->arr_base;
    for (size_t idx = 0;  idx < arr->arr_count;  ++idx, ++book)
        printf("Last: %s First: %s Title: %s\n",
            book->book_last,book->book_first,book->book_title);

    // release storage for each book
    book = arr->arr_base;
    for (size_t idx = 0;  idx < arr->arr_count;  ++idx, ++book) {
        free(book->book_last);
        free(book->book_first);
        free(book->book_title);
    }

    // release array storage
    arrfree(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program input:

```
Lambstewer Abel A Tale of Two Cities
Smith John      A baker's tale
Jones Fred      Never On Sunday
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
Gimme Books's Titles:
Lambstewer Abel A Tale of Two Cities
Smith John      A baker's tale
Jones Fred      Never On Sunday
Last: Lambstewer First: Abel Title: A Tale of Two Cities
Last: Smith First: John Title: A baker's tale
Last: Jones First: Fred Title: Never On Sunday
```