# Dynamic array in structs

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have a problem using dynamic memory in C.
I am creating a struct whose data is a number and a pointer to another struct (in short, an array of struct). The goal is for the parent struct to store an array of another struct using dynamic memory.

The problem I have is to access the cells of the created array, because I don't know if it's due to syntax issues (I'm new to C), or that I'm creating the array wrong, I can't modify the information contained in each cell of the contained array inside the parent struct. I can only modify by default the first cell.

This is my code, any idea or suggestion will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

typedef struct {
    char string[64];
    void* date;
    void* colour;
} DataState;

typedef struct {
    int number;
    DataState* array;
} Book;

Book* makeBook (int number){
    int a=5;
    void* auxiliary=&a;
    Book* book_A=(Book*)(malloc(sizeof(Book)));
    book_A->number=number;
    book_A->array=(DataState*)(malloc(number*sizeof(DataState))); //creating array of structs inside main struct.
    //And what I want to do is something like this, modify the information contained in cells of the array of structs of the main struct.
    book_A->array[3]->date=auxiliary;
    return book_A;
}
```

From already thank you very much.

Comment: Post your error message(s) (as text, please, not as an image).  One problem: `book_A->array[3]` is a structure, not a pointer because the `[3]` dereferences the `array` pointer to access the fourth `struct` in the array.  So instead of `book_A->array[3]->date=auxiliary;`, it should be `book_A->array[3].date=auxiliary;`

Comment: `a` only exists in `makeBook`, it disappears when `makeBook` returns, so the address of where it used to live (`auxiliary` and `->date`) is no longer valid.

Comment: If you have syntax issues the compiler will tell you and you will not be able to run your program.

Comment: so yano,would you recommend me to make a malloc so that when the function finishes, that pointer is saved? Well, as I understand it, once the execution of the function is finished, it is deleted from the activation register?

Comment: Please see my recent answer: [Creation of Dynamic Array of Strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73737192/5382650). It is very similar to what you're doing. That OP just wanted strings, but [ironically] I gave an example that used an array of book structs.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
book_A->array[3]->date=auxiliary;
```

you assign a value of `auxiliary` to the 3rd element of an array, but `auxiliary` is defined as

```
void* auxiliary=&a;
```

while `a` is an *automatic* variable in your function.

Automatic variables disappear at the return from the function, hence the pointer assigned to `book_A->array[3]->date` becomes invalid as soon as the `return` is executed.

Comment: And how could this be solved, so that auxiliary remains pointed to said value regardless if the function finished its execution?

Comment: @Juan598 you need to `malloc` space for `a` as you have for other things in the function: `int* a = malloc(sizeof *a); ... ->date=a`. But really, I'd consider a re-architecture. Does `date` even need to be a `void` pointer?

Comment: yes because it can be int, array of strings, bool, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data saved in `a` to remain valid after `makeBook` returns, then you must allocate it in more persistent storage than automatic.  You've essentially done this:

```c
int* foo()
{
  int a = 5;
  // WRONG, cannot return the address of a local variable
  return &a;
}

int main(void)
{
  int* a_addr = foo();
  // WRONG, invokes undefined behavior
  printf("a = %d\n", *a_addr);
}
```

If you want `a` to persist outside of `foo`, a possible option is:

```c
int* foo()
{
  int* a = malloc(sizeof *a);
  // always check the return value of malloc
  if (a != NULL)
  {
    *a = 5;
  }
  // this is ok. `a` is still in automatic storage, but this _returns_ its
  // value, which is a pointer to data _not_ in automatic storage.
  return a;
}

int main(void)
{
  int* a_addr = foo();
  // still must check here, malloc in `foo` could have failed. Probably
  // better to design an architecture where you only check validity once
  if (a_addr != NULL)
  {
    printf("a = %d\n", *a_addr);  // prints a = 5
    // don't forget to `free(a_addr)` when you're done with it, or you can
    // let the OS clean up the memory when the process exits.
  }
  else
  {
    // handle error how you want
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of mem!\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```